# How can I list the first indexed row for multiple items in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am looking to create a table that is specific to the index number that can be matched in multiple items. So for example, if I want just the items for index [0], I want it to output:

```
1a 2a
1b 2b
```

How can I achieve this in my html code? The html is formatted as is so I can write successive, repeated values.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.items[0] = ["1a", "2a"];
  $scope.items[1] = ["3a", "4a"];
  $scope.items[2] = ["5a", null];
  $scope.moreitems = [];
  $scope.moreitems[0] = ["1b", "2b"];
  $scope.moreitems[1] = ["3b", "4b"];
  $scope.moreitems[2] = ["5b", null];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table class="table">
      <tr ng-repeat="tr in items">
        <td ng-repeat="td in tr track by $index">{{td}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="tr in moreitems">
        <td ng-repeat="td in tr track by $index">{{td}}</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer cause my HTML markup was incorrect. But the jist is to change the data structure to combine both of those values `$scope.itemsCollection [0] = {items: ["1a", "2a"], moreitems = ["1b", "2b"]}` and ng-repeat on that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to create two rows in the first loop:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.items[0] = ["1a", "2a"];
  $scope.items[1] = ["3a", "4a"];
  $scope.items[2] = ["5a", null];
  $scope.moreitems = [];
  $scope.moreitems[0] = ["1b", "2b"];
  $scope.moreitems[1] = ["3b", "4b"];
  $scope.moreitems[2] = ["5b", null];
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <table class="table">
      <tr ng-repeat-start="arr in items" ng-init="itemIndex=$index">
        <td ng-repeat="data in arr track by $index">{{data}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td ng-repeat="data in moreitems[itemIndex] track by $index">{{data}}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Special repeat start and end points](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)